# how to load PDF file in website page using C#

Tags: c#

how to load PDF file in website page using C#

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you send a file to the browser.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306654

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
             //Set the appropriate ContentType.
        Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
             //Get the physical path to the file.
        string FilePath = MapPath("acrobat.pdf");
             //Write the file directly to the HTTP content output stream.
        Response.WriteFile(FilePath);
            Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: And whether it opens in the browser, or prompts to launch an application (or save) will depend on local settings that the server cannot control.

Comment: thanx too mush but i want to show it in part of the page in div or panel so that the rest of my page has another controls

Comment: @sama, you can't do it unless you pull it in from to an Iframe or such.  You can't mix different content types on the same page.